# IIS 8 - Domain and URL rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I am trying to rewrite domain and URL of request so when user goes to URL:

`http://somedomain.com/`

he sees content of:

`https://serverdomain.com/applications/somedomain/`

Of course, anything that is appended to `somedomain.com/` should also be appended to `applications/somedomain/`

I installed ARR 3 and Failed Request Logging, but I can't get to this result. Moreover, after installing ARR, 404 errors start throwing 502.2.

The best rule I got was:

```
<rule name="test-domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="somedomain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://serverdomain.com/applications/somedomain{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

It almost works, but I don't know why it takes me to home page (e.g. `https://serverdomain.com/`).

When I set action type to Redirect it looks OK, but I need this rewrited, so user sees original URL.

Comment: Try ` <match url="(.*)" />`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Do some digging first.

Comment: @LexLi I did, but this guided me to this point where I still know nothing. I spent like 20 hours searching and trying before asking on SO.